# Obtain path from unordered list of edges

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

How to sort my graph that contains edges with only >begin, end< data. I don't know where my journey starts or where it ends, so I can't just take one where journey begins and append to it missing one's.

```
graph_before=[
    {"order" : ("Stockholm", "New York JFK")},
    {"order" : ("Barcelona", "Girona Airport")},
    {"order" : ("Madrid", "Barcelona")},
    {"order" : ("Girona Airport", "Stockholm")},
]


graph_after=[
    {"order" : ("Madrid", "Barcelona")},
    {"order" : ("Barcelona", "Girona Airport")},
    {"order" : ("Girona Airport", "Stockholm")},
    {"order" : ("Stockholm", "New York JFK")},
]
# Trip Madrid > New York JFK
```

Comment: hint: the one that doesn't appear as a second element in any tuple is the one to start from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you have an *unordered* list of edges, what you're looking for is the [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) connecting them all, which is the [longest possible path in the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). For that you could build a directed graph using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/), and look for the longest path with [`nx.dag_longest_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path.html):

```
import networkx as nx

edges = [tuple(*d.values()) for d in graph_before]
# [('Stockholm', 'New York JFK'), ('Barcelona', 'Girona Airport')...
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
longest_path = nx.dag_longest_path(G)
graph_after = list(zip(longest_path[:-1], longest_path[1:]))
```

---

```
print(graph_after)
[('Madrid', 'Barcelona'),
 ('Barcelona', 'Girona Airport'),
 ('Girona Airport', 'Stockholm'),
 ('Stockholm', 'New York JFK')]
​
```

For the same structure as `graph_before`:

```
graph_after = [{'order': edge} for edge in graph_after]

print(graph_after)
[{'order': ('Madrid', 'Barcelona')},
 {'order': ('Barcelona', 'Girona Airport')},
 {'order': ('Girona Airport', 'Stockholm')},
 {'order': ('Stockholm', 'New York JFK')}]
```